# Access nested Select query get the a row with a max value

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have two tables and need to create a query that lists all of the first table and a field from a second table where a second field in the second table is a maximum value.

```
Table1
MatID | MatCode | Name |
-----------------------
1     | A       | Ex1  |
2     | B       | Ex2  |
3     | C       | Ex3  |

Table 2
MatID | MatCode | OtherName | Count |
------------------------------------
1     | A       | Red       | 5     |
1     | A       | Blue      | 15    |
1     | A       | Green     | 2     |
2     | B       | Red       | 25    |
2     | B       | Blue      | 3     |
2     | B       | Green     | 1     |
3     | C       | Red       | 2     |
3     | C       | Blue      | 3     |
3     | C       | Green     | 11    |
```

The Result would be

```
MatID | MatCode | Name | OtherName |
-----------------------------------
1     | A       | Ex1  | Blue
2     | B       | Ex2  | Red
3     | C       | Ex3  | Green
```

Hope this is clear.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should only be storing `MatCode` in the first table, rather than in both tables.  This has nothing to do with your question; it is just a suggestion for modeling the data.

Comment: Thanks, you're correct. The real table is way more complex and does only have the one.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select top 1 t2.OtherName
        from table2 as t2
        where t2.MatId = t1.MatId
        order by count desc, matid  -- to prevent duplicates
       ) as OtherName
from table1 as t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT Z.MatID, Z.MatCode, Z.Name, C.OtherName
FROM
(SELECT A.MatID, A.MatCode, A.Name, MAX(Count) as Max_Count
FROM
Table1 A INNER JOIN table2 B
ON A.MatID = B.MatID AND A.MatCode = B.MatCode
GROUP BY A.MatID, A.MatCode, A.Name ) Z
INNER JOIN Table2 C
ON Z.MatID = C.MatID AND Z.MatCode = C.MatCode AND Z.Max_Count = C.Count;
```